# Reduction vs MapToInt to obtain sum in Streams API

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Following streams produces the same result however there are two different ways to achieve this.

```
Person.stream().map(Person::getAge).reduce(Integer::sum).get();

Person.stream().mapToInt( Person::getAge).sum();
```

I want to know difference among two and which one is better.

Comment: what is the data type of age field in Person class?

Comment: Its int. or integer type ..

Comment: If that is an int the latter outperforms the former due to auto boxing and unboxing.

Comment: Not sure, checked JDK code for both but unable to understand that is why came here to seek help

Comment: Do you want an explanatory answer? If so let me know so that I can elaborate my comment above.

Comment: Yes, Please that would be great.

Comment: @Eugene - Completely agree with you, but Ravindra is saying he knows something